# Como mostrar uma imagem enquanto o slide de fotos carrega

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um slide de fotos que é baseado em ul e vai carregando as fotos para montar o slide. Abaixo o trecho que tras as fotos:

```
<ul id="slide" class="bxslider" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
  <?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($photos);$i++){
              <li class="propertyinfoli">
    <a class="osmodal" href="<?php echo JURI::root()?>caminho-da-imagem">
    <img src="<?php echo JURI::root()?>caminho-da-imagem"/>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Enquanto ele carrega as fotos, essas fotos vão aparecendo uma embaixo da outra, deixando a página com uma aparência estranha, até carregar tudo, que é quando fica alinhado certinho.

Eu queria que, enquanto carrega as fotos, ficasse 1 foto visivel, ou que carregasse oculto, aí quando carregar tudo, ele mostra o slide. ALguns slides tem mais de 25 fotos, aí demora uns 10 seg para carregar.

Sabem se é possivel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Neste caso, uma solução é iniciar o slider escondido (display: none), realizar um loading via JavaScript e exibir o slider quando todas imagens estiverem carregadas. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```js
$imgs = $('#slide img');
$status = $('#status');

var loaded = 0;
var total = $imgs.length;

$status.html('Carregando');
$imgs.each(function() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    loaded++;
    
    if(loaded == total) {
      $('#slide').show();
      $status.html('Carregamento completo!');
    }
  }
  img.src= $(this).attr('src');
});
```

```css
#slide {
  display: none;
}
.propertyinfoli img {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="status"></p>
<ul id="slide" class="bxslider" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
  <li class="propertyinfoli">
    <a class="osmodal" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/></a>
  </li>
  <li class="propertyinfoli">
    <a class="osmodal" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/></a>
  </li>
  <li class="propertyinfoli">
    <a class="osmodal" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/87646/horsehead-nebula-dark-nebula-constellation-orion-87646.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/87646/horsehead-nebula-dark-nebula-constellation-orion-87646.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```